# Use BigQuery to find the running total number of users per day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some user data as below, and I would like to have a running total of the number of unique users I have seen per day. Starting with a basic query:

```
SELECT
  day, user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS cnt

FROM
  (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
  (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
  (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
  (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
  (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
  (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),

  (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
  (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),
  (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),
  (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),

  (select "C" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
  (select "C" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),

  (select "D" user_id, "2015-02-04" day)

GROUP BY
  day, user_id
```

The results of this group are:

```
Row day         user_id cnt  
1   2015-02-01  A        1   
2   2015-02-01  B        1   
3   2015-02-02  B        1   
4   2015-02-01  C        1   
5   2015-02-02  C        1   
6   2015-02-04  D        1
```

I can see that there are three unique users on `2015-02-01` and no new users until `2015-02-04`, where there is only one (user D).

I need the results to look like this:

```
Row  day         running_count
1    2015-02-01  3
2    2015-02-02  3
3    2015-02-03  3
3    2015-02-04  4
```

Where `running_count` corresponds to the running tally of the number of NEW users per day. For example, `2015-02-02` is zero because only user_id's B & C show up on that day, but they were already counted on `2015-02-01`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only look at the MIN(date), SUM() OVER() for running count. It will be missing the interim dates, but you can get that with a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT day, SUM(c) OVER(ORDER BY day)
FROM (
  SELECT day, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) c
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(day) day, user_id
    FROM
      (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
      (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
      (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
      (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
      (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
      (select "A" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),

      (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
      (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),
      (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),
      (select "B" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),

      (select "C" user_id, "2015-02-01" day),
      (select "C" user_id, "2015-02-02" day),

      (select "D" user_id, "2015-02-04" day)
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) 
  GROUP BY day
)
```